# ArcGIS: Create polygon using file containing point coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinates, polygon-creation, cogo

I have a text file containing the projected coordinates of the points that define a single polygon. The X, Y coordinates are separated by Tab

Is there a tool in ArcGIS similar to "Add X,Y Data" in ArcMap, that can be used to automatically create polygons FC, not point FC?

I use ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20020/points-to-polygon

Comment: There is an ArcGIS Idea for this - search on "ungenerate" (the opposite tool is also mentioned).

Comment: If you have an ArcInfo license, then you can use the [Minimum Bounding Geometry (Data Management](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003q000000.htm) tool to create a convex hull (ref. http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/39/15768) from your points.

Comment: Erica, wouldn't that be a two-step process? 1) Create points FC - 2) Create polygon using the Points FC. I was looking for a single tool that can automatically do that, so should I assume there isn't any? Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't any tool to do this in 1 single step, you should either:

1. convert your text file to points
2. convert points to lines with [Points to Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003s000000)
3. convert lines to polygons with [Feature to Polygon](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Feature_To_Polygon/00170000003n000000/) (Advanced licnese required)

Or:

Use arcpy :) - no specific license required.

See an example at the bottom of the page [Writing geometries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002z0000001v000000). The code converts a list of coordinates (a text file can be regarded as such a list) into polylines, you can easily modify it to create polygons.

Answer (score 1):

On the ArcGIS Idea website, someone suggested this toolbox http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/geoprocessing/details?entryID=F25C5576-1422-2418-A060-04188EBD33A9 that has a tool called "Create features from text File", which can automatically create point, lines and polygons Feature Classes from text files containing coordinates.
Worked for me.