# How to make a square out of two points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, tiles, csv

I have a csv file with two x and y columns. (x,y,x,y). The coordinates represent tiles which I want to visualize in ArcMap. But I dont know how to do it.

As you can see in the picture below, given is x1, y1 and x2, y2. The coordinates describe the upper left corner and the lower right corner of the tile. When I open the coordinates in ArcGIS it only visualizes two points. Is there a possibility that ArcMap calculates a square out of it? Like it is drawn in the picture. Somehow I have to compute the coordinates of upper right corner and lower right corner. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean be tiles? With two coordinated per row(=feature), you'll get lines (not tiles =squares?)?

Comment: @Iris Sorry, I described my question really bad. I edited the post and uploaded a picture to make it clearer what I mean.

Comment: Essentially, you'll want to find the deltas in the x & y coordinates between both points and look at the sign to see if you need to add/subtract it from each to get the missing `UL` and `LR` coordinates.

Comment: Your diagram has a rectangle and not a square. Also, is your requirement that the sides be orientated NS & EW?  If not, the question becomes noticeably harder.

Answer (score 5):

Solution below works for Advanced license only!

1. Create multipoint dataset by dissolving your points using common
   attribute:

[image]

2. Create features envelopes:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You really already have the data you need (assuming these are all actual squares):

1. (X1, Y1) - Upper Left
2. (X1, Y2) - Lower Left
3. (X2, Y2) - Lower Right
4. (X2, Y1) - Upper Right

Getting ArcMap to build them is another matter in itself.  I don't personally know how to do this exactly.  You could convert your points to lines (you'll need to add an ID field to group them with) and then convert the lines to polygons.  Or you could use ArcPy and build the squares from the points manually.

Comment: Thank you. I will try using Arcpy tomorrow. When I have all four points of the square, is it possible to make one polygon out of the area within the 4 points with arcpy?

Comment: Check out this related question, it seems to have some good answers about doing this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111742/arcgis-create-polygon-using-file-containing-point-coordinates

Comment: +1. My comment above way over-complicates things.

Comment: i wish i listened in math class. I feel pretty dumb not knowing this LOL. Thank you!