# Polygon to Point File

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

On ArcGIS 10.2, when I create a polygon from a point file, Why does it only draw a line for three sides, and how can I fix that?

Comment: What were the precise steps that you used to "create a polygon from a point file"?

Comment: Can you be more specific about the name of the tool you are using to "create a polygon from a point file"? Please take the tour http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @jbchurchill So I had a point file, I went to arctoolbox, to data management, features, and then points to line

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested details.  It sounds like you asked the software to create a line (not a polygon) from your points, which it did.

Comment: Points to Line has a Sort Order parameter that defines the order the Points are drawn. If this is omitted, the points might be added as they exist in the Point FC.

Answer (score 2):

Your question refers to creating a **polygon** from points, however as you state in your comment you're using the **point** to line tool. You then need to convert that line to a polygon using the Feature to Polygon tool. If your point file is simple, such as near a square, you can just use the Minimum Bounding Geometry tool to skip the point to line step

Answer (score 1):

As it shows in the documentation for [Points to Line](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003s000000) the points input will be connected by a line. It sounds like you're looking for a closed geometry, which will require an additional step of [Feature to Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Feature_To_Polygon/00170000003n000000/) according to [this answered question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111742/arcgis-create-polygon-using-file-containing-point-coordinates) ...it does look like you'll need an additional line to close it off though