# How to draw polygon by using different point in different UTM zone

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I am going to calculate the area of agricultural land the lays in different UTM zones (36 and 37) by using different GPS collected data.  I have GPS XY coordinates and I want to use these to draw a polygon. How?

Comment: i have GPS Xy cordinate point and by using the data wants to draw a polygon in Arc GIS 10.3.1.

Comment: Are the coordinates in a table? Take a look at this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/111742/arcgis-create-polygon-using-file-containing-point-coordinates

Comment: Set your DataFrame or FC to correct UTM zone, Start Editing, CreateFeatures, right-click view, enter GPS coordinate by selecting Absolute X,Y.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert all data to geographic coordinates to draw or create a custom System.
Converting all the data to gcs wgs84  will help the drawing process but could cause problems on measuring. The Best solution is to convert to gcs wgs84 draw The polygon and convert back to utm for measuring.