# How to remove all transparency from all layers?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, layers, transparency-opacity

I am using ArcMap 10.1 and I would like to remove all transparency from all the layers in the map at once.

Answer (score 3):

Working off the answer given by Dan, this script will remove the transparency from all layers if you run it in the python window in arcmap.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames (mxd, "Layers") [0]
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers (mxd,"", df):
    lyr.transparency = 0
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
mxd.save
del mxd
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your layers and use `arcpy.mapping.Layer` [**`arcpy.mapping`**](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) and set the transparency property.

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/18814/how-to-change-symbology-of-multiple-layers-at-once-using-arcmap-arcpy for an application of this.