# Can't display raster in mxd as RGB

Tags: arcpy, raster, symbology

I have a script that iterates through a folder of jpgs, clips them to a grid, inserts them to an mxd, and exports them. My original problem was when I added the clipped raster from a standalone script to my mxd, it would automatically render it as a 1 band stretched image when a 3 band RGB is desired. In the python window I was able to use copy raster (management) with the "ColormapToRGB" parameter to create a layer that was displayed correctly. The problem now is when I run it from a standalone it doesn't automatically add the RGB to my TOC like it did from the python window. I instead have to add the RGB with another line like I did with my original clipped raster and I run into the same 1 band rendering issue. Anyone one know how I can get the RGB image to appear in my TOC with the correct display?

```
import arcpy

#Define workspaces
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\FolderPath" 
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\FilePath.mxd")

#Define layer locations
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]
quads = "C:\\Geodatabase.gdb\\Quads_14"
qSelect = "C:\Geodatabase.gdb\qSelect"
outRast = "C:\\Geodatabase.gdb\\rastClip"

#Slice strings for SelectLayerByAttribute
qname = path[12:-4].replace("_", " ")
qnameUp = qname.upper()
sqlString = "NAME LIKE" + " '" + qnameUp + "'"

#Inserts each JPEG in folder and does all geoprocessing/map labelling/exporting
for jpg in arcpy.ListRasters("2*","JPG"):
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(quads, qSelect, sqlString)
    desc = arcpy.Describe(qSelect)
    extent = str(desc.extent)
    arcpy.Clip_management(in_raster=jpg, rectangle=extent, out_raster=outRast, in_template_dataset=qSelect, nodata_value="256",clipping_geometry="ClippingGeometry", maintain_clipping_extent="NO_MAINTAIN_EXTENT")
    topo = arcpy.mapping.Layer(outRast)
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, topo, "TOP")
    arcpy.CopyRaster_management(outRast, out_rasterdataset="C:/FilePath", nodata_value="256", onebit_to_eightbit="NONE",colormap_to_RGB="ColormapToRGB", scale_pixel_value="NONE", RGB_to_Colormap="NONE")

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
mxd.save()
del mxd, df
```

Comment: have you looked at this answer on [How to change Symbology of Multiple Layers at once using ArcMap/ArcPy?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/18822/64785)?

Comment: I have tried that function, but to my understanding it's not a symbology issue its a rendering issue. It would change the symbology to match the reference later but it would still be rendered as "stretched" and not RGB.